# parse unity WWW api response to model

Tags: c#, parsing, unity-game-engine

How do i parse my webapi response into a usefull model?

This is my api call:

```
  IEnumerator GetQuestion(){
    string input = new QuestionThemeRequest(){ QuestionTheme = "BAJS" }.ToString();
    Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
    headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (input);
    WWW www = new WWW ("http://localhost:52603/api/Question/GetRandomQuestionByTheme", body, headers);
    yield return www;
}
```

and here

```
   public class Question{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Answere { get; set; }
}
```

i tried something like this:

```
Question q = new Question();
q = GetQuestion();
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's based on content of your server's response.

if it's JSON you can use [SimpleJSON](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) to parse it.

@MX D solves your delay issues.

It's example code but don't forget I assume your www.text is JSON type.

```
using SimpleJSON;

IEnumerator GetQuestion(){
    string input = new QuestionThemeRequest(){ QuestionTheme = "BAJS" }.ToString();
    Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
    headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (input);
    WWW www = new WWW ("http://localhost:52603/api/Question/GetRandomQuestionByTheme", body, headers);
    yield return www;
    if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))) {
       print( "Error downloading: " + www.error );
    } else {
       JSONNode questionJSON = JSONNode.Parse (www.text);
       Question q = new Question();
       q.Id = questionJSON["id"];
       q.Answere = questionJSON["Answere"];
    }
}
```

More good solution is

```
using SimpleJSON;

public YourClass : MonoBehaviour{
    public delegate void WWWCalback(WWW wwwData);
    private void answersCallback(WWW wwwData){
        JSONNode questionJSON = JSONNode.Parse (wwwData.text);
        Question q = new Question();
        q.Id = questionJSON["id"];
        q.Answere = questionJSON["Answere"];
    }
    private void getAnswers(){
      StartCoroutine(GetQuestion(answersCallback));
    }
    IEnumerator GetQuestion(WWWCalback callback){
      string input = new QuestionThemeRequest(){ QuestionTheme = "BAJS" }.ToString();
      Hashtable headers = new Hashtable();
      headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
      byte[] body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes (input);
      WWW www = new WWW ("http://localhost:52603/api/Question/GetRandomQuestionByTheme", body, headers);
      yield return www;
      if((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(www.error))) {
            print( "Error downloading: " + www.error );
      } else {
            callback(www);
      }
    }
}
```

Like that. Maybe some syntax or another problems occurs. I don't check it.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided will not run, as you are trying to call it like a void. But it is a Coroutine (IEnumerator). For this to properly run you will need to start the coroutine, which can be done as following

```
StartCoroutine(GetQuestion());
```

or

```
StartCoroutine("GetQuestion");
```

Do keep in mind that the second option will no longer be possible as of unity 5.0

For more information about coroutines you should check out the [unity docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html)

Comment: ok, so i added that. But my question remains. What do i do with www to get something out of it. I tried to do www.text but that leaves me with an object that i don't know what it looks like.

Comment: Then debug what it returns. Debugging is the way to find out what it gives ya